# Extract a matrix under a specific string from a text file using matlab

Tags: matlab

example

My text file is like

string 1 
12 13 14 16
11 41 25 26
32 25 26 27

string 2
23 15 26 28 
12 15 19 17
35 65 84 12

string 3 and so on...

I want that if I ask for string 1 , it will give me the corresponging matrix under string 1 and the size of the matrix is also not known i.e.
12 13 14 16
11 41 25 26
32 25 26 27

will anyone tell me how to do this?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following:

1 - Convert string to integer/matrix

```
M1 = str2num(string1) - http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2num.html
M2 = str2num(string2)
```

2 - If you want to find the corresponding values, just compare:

```
for i=1:length(M1)
     [~,M3(i)]=ismember(M1(i),M2)
end
```

`M3` will give you the indexes that are a match in `M2`.